# What actually happens in the compiler in this case

Tags: java, compiler-construction, stringbuilder

I have a small question, given the following snippet:

```
StringBuilder stringBuild = new StringBuilder(3);
stringBuild.append("hello");
System.out.println(stringBuild+2); // if I omit the (+2) bit hence only stringBUild it works
```

Does it call automatically `toString()` on object only in some circumstances? (circumstances: either no operation at all or a previous string contatanation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler **never** calls `toString()` on a method argument implicitly.

What you are probably thinking of, is that there is [an overload of `System.out.println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) which takes an `Object` (rather than a String) - this is the method that the compiler would link to.  And this particular implementation of the method calls `toString` on the Object passed in (at runtime).  That's just code though, it's nothing to do with compiler behaviour.

So passing in an Object to `System.out.println` "works".  Passing in `stringBuild+2` simply doesn't compile - there's no `+` operator on `StringBuilder` which takes an int.  (And you can't create one yourself as Java doesn't allow for operator overloading.)

As ADTC and tom point out, there is implicit String conversion with the *second* argument to string concatenation (the `+` operator for strings).  So while `stringBuild` doesn't have a `+` operator, `stringBuild.toString()` would, and you *could* call `stringBuild.toString()+2`.

Comment: You may want to add that there's no custom operator overloading in Java. All arithmetic operators are used for arithmetic operations only, with the exception of `+` which is used for string concatenation (_is there anything else?_). The `+` sign only works on objects of the `String` type. So doing `stringBuild.toString()+2` will work.

Comment: Example with implicit call to `toString()`: `"hello " + new Object() { public String toString() { return "world!"; } }`. Refer to JLS [§15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) and [§5.1.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11).

Comment: Thanks both - good points and I've included them in the answer.  @tom, I take from [JLS §5.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.4) that string conversion only ever happens for the strign concatenation operator.  Let me know if you're aware of another context where this occurs.